# How to log new records during SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to log new and modified records. This code works just fine for Modified Records.

But with Added records, there is an issue. Since it is new to the Database, there is not yet a primary key for it.  So there is no way to log which record was added.

However, if I try to log the records after the save, the EntityState is no longer Added. So I don't know what was added.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to save a list of the new records, and then after the save, then Log the changes. But that seems like a workaround.

Is there some way to resolve this?

```
 private List<Event> LogChanges(EntityEntry entityEntry, Enums.TableNames tableName)
    {
        List<Event> result = new List<Event>();
        var databaseValues = entityEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
        foreach (var property in entityEntry.CurrentValues.Properties.Where(a=> a.Name !="TenantId"))
        {
            string original = databaseValues[property]?.ToString();
            string current = entityEntry.CurrentValues[property]?.ToString();

            if(!object.Equals(original,current))
            {
                result.Add(
                    new Event()
                    {
                        AppUserId = this._appUserProvider.CurrentAppUserId,
                        EventDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
                        EventTypeId = (int)Enums.EventTypes.Modified,
                        TenantId = databaseValues.GetValue<int>("TenantId"),
                        RecordId = databaseValues.GetValue<int>("Id"),
                        ColumnName = property.Name,
                        OriginalValue = original,
                        NewValue = current,
                        TableId = (int)tableName
                    });
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers) adds triggers to EntityFrameworkCore. Using the Triggers it provides is a much cleaner way to accomplish the above.